# Анимация точек слайдера

Tags: javascript, css, animate

[image]

Нужна помощь с анимацией точек в слайдере. Нужно чтобы активный слайд имел широкую точку, а при пролистывании слайдера эта широкая точка должна плавно переезжать на другой активный слайд

Answer (score 0):

Можно jQuery использовать:

```
.dot {
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.active-dot {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```
$('.slider').on('slideChange', function() {
  $('.dot').removeClass('active-dot');
  var currentSlide = $('.slider').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
  $('.dot').eq(currentSlide).addClass('active-dot');
});
```